# What language is this (javascript?)?

Tags: javascript

I found this javascript-looking code but I'm not sure what kind of language it is.

I got it from a website called [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/)

When I ran it in a javascript console it didn't run

```
noStroke();
//variables
var cloud1a = 365;
var cloud1b = 340;
var cloud1c = 320;
var cloud1d = 340;
var cloud2a = 225;
var cloud2b = 170;
var cloud2c = 200;
var cloud2d = 200;
var cloud3a = 35;
var cloud3b = 60;
var cloud3c = 80;
var cloud3d = 55;
var fast = 0.3;

var draw = function() {
background(168, 246, 250);
//clouds
fill(255, 255, 255); 
ellipse(cloud1a,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud1b,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud1c,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud1d,25,50,50);

ellipse(cloud2a,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud2b,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud2c,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud2d,25,50,50);

ellipse(cloud3a,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud3b,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud3c,45,60,50);
ellipse(cloud3d,25,50,50);

if (cloud1a > 418) {
    cloud1a = 0;
}
if (cloud1b > 418) {
    cloud1b = 0;
}
if (cloud1c > 418) {
    cloud1c = 0;
}
if (cloud1d > 418) {
    cloud1d = 0;
}
if (cloud2a > 418) {
    cloud2a = 0;
}
if (cloud2b > 418) {
    cloud2b = 0;
}
if (cloud2c > 418) {
    cloud2c = 0;
}
if (cloud2d > 418) {
    cloud2d = 0;
}
if (cloud3a > 418) {
    cloud3a = 0;
}
if (cloud3b > 418) {
    cloud3b = 0;
}
if (cloud3c > 418) {
    cloud3c = 0;
}
if (cloud3d > 418) {
    cloud3d = 0;
}

cloud1a += fast; 
cloud1b += fast; 
cloud1c += fast;  
cloud1d += fast;  
cloud2a += fast;  
cloud2b += fast;  
cloud2c += fast;  
cloud2d += fast;  
cloud3a += fast;  
cloud3b += fast;  
cloud3c += fast; 
cloud3d += fast; 

//Dirt
fill(36, 1, 1);
rect(0,340,400,61);

//Grass
fill(75, 186, 6);
rect(0,340,402,5);

//sun
fill(255, 213, 0);
ellipse(10,10,140,140);

//ball
fill(255, 0, 0);
ellipse(30, 315, 50, 50);

//title
fill(240, 36, 0);
textSize(20);
text("Baucing ball: The Game",117,40);
fill(0, 0, 0);
textSize(10);
text("Created by: Cristian Torres & Israel Jimenez",120,55);
};
```

Comment: I think it uses some library (graphic library) and you don't include it, so it does not run. The language itself I believe is still javascript.

Comment: Looks like Processing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like http://processingjs.org/.

You can find all the function in http://processingjs.org/reference/.